# Android Javascript WebView

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I have an app where my min API is 16, and I want to evaluate some javascript on a web view and when I have

```
mWebView.evaluateJavascript("(function()...)");
```

I get a compile error saying this is only available in API 19 and higher, so how can I evaluate javascript in a web view for the API below 19, I have but above code in a if statement for API 19 and above, but how can I do this in API below 19?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Before API 19, you have to use [`WebView.loadUrl()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String%29) with the `javaScript` protocol to evaluate JavaScript within the currently loaded page:

```
String javaScript = // Some JavaScript code here

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    mWebView.evaluateJavascript(javaScript, null);
} else {
    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + javaScript);
}
```

Comment: How will you evaluate a js function with parameters? Something function example(a,b) {
 return (a+b);
}